# MySQL SELECT FROM 3 Table with where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

**Task:**

```
ID   | UID  | PID   | TITLE    |
1    | 2    | 0     | task 1   |
2    | 2    | 1     | task 1-1 |
3    | 3    | 0     | task 2   |
4    | 2    | 0     | task 3   |
5    | 2    | 0     | task 4   |
```

**todo:**

```
ID   | UID  | TXID   | TID      | TITLE    |
1    | 2    | 1      | 1        | todo1    |
2    | 2    | 1      | 1        | todo2    |
3    | 3    | 2      | 3        | todo3    |
4    | 2    | 4      | 4        | todo4    |
5    | 2    | 5      | 5        | todo5    |
```

**timix:**

```
ID   | UID  | STATUS   | 
1    | 2    | 0        |
2    | 2    | 1        |
3    | 3    | 0        | 
4    | 2    | 1        | 
5    | 2    | 0        |
```

I need statement look like this query but corrected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM todo,task,timix 
WHERE task.id = todo.tid 
  AND todo.uid=2 
  AND task.pid=0 
  AND timix.id = todo.txid 
  AND timix.status = 0
```

this is description of variable:

```
uid = user id
txid = timix id
tid = task id
pid = parent id
```

**I need :**
  show tasks have todo`s and pid=0 and uid=2 and timix_status=0

Comment: do you mean that `task.uid = 2 AND todo.uid=2 AND timix.uid=2` or `task.uid = 2 OR todo.uid=2 OR timix.uid=2`? this column confuse me a lot.

Comment: sorry. we have additional environment. in todo table only have tid. and tid is task id. and this tasks is ONLY sub tasks. in Other words: we dont have tasks that pid= 0 in todo table and tid field.

Comment: @Alex we need only task for user id = 2 also timix and todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you did not provide your expected result, I am not sure what exactly do you need.

Here is my approach

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec3c88/2

```
SELECT * 
FROM task
INNER JOIN todo
ON task.id = todo.tid 
  AND todo.uid=2 
INNER JOIN timix 
ON timix.id = todo.txid 
  AND timix.status = 0
WHERE task.pid=0
```

But it returns same set as your original query. So what's wrong with that result? what record do you want to exclude? or to add?

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't want to join but use `EXISTS`? At least that's how I interpret your "I need".

```
SELECT *
       FROM task
       WHERE task.pid = 0
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM todo
                                WHERE todo.tid = task.id
                                      AND todo.uid = 2
                                      AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                                         FROM timix
                                                         WHERE timix.id = todo.txid
                                                               AND timix.status = 0));
```

Or you might want to keep the join in the subquery.

```
SELECT *
       FROM task
       WHERE task.pid = 0
             AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM todo
                                     INNER JOIN timix
                                                ON timix.id = todo.txid
                                WHERE todo.tid = task.id
                                      AND todo.uid = 2
                                      AND timix.status = 0);
```

Another alternative might be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT task.* FROM todo,task,timix WHERE task.id = todo.tid AND todo.uid=2 AND task.pid=0 AND timix.id = todo.txid AND timix.status = 0;
```

The `DISTINCT` dedupes the result. 
(But consider using explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the `FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.attribute1 = table2.attribute2` variant. It's easier to see what's meant with the explicit one.)

It depends on your system (data, indexes) which one performs best.

Comment: `WHERE task.pid = 0 ` don't work. because mysql see unknown culms when Select only form todo

Comment: @BenDehqan: Sorry I mixed up some things. Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

simple,

```
Select t.* from Task t join
todo td on t.ID = td.TID join
timix tx on td.TXID = tx.ID
where t.UID = 2 and tx.STATUS = 0
```